# How do I get today's UTC date/time for 00:00:00 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

When I type the following snippet of code:

```
new Date('2018-11-01')
```

I get a date object that represents the following ISO string.

```
"2018-11-01T00:00:00Z"
```

I believe it represents the UTC date/time for 2018-11-01 at 00:00:00.

How can I obtain the current day's UTC date/time object for 00:00:00 programmatically?

Currently, I have the following snippet that should achieve my objective but it feels a little awkward since I'm converting a string obtained from moment back into a date object.

```
new Date(moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'))
```

**Would love to see a 1 stop solution using Vanilla JS or a library like momentJS.**

Comment: i believe momentJS provide tools for getting UTC time

Comment: I struggled to find it in the docs :( everything seems to be about converting / displaying in UTC time rather than getting today’s date/time at 00:00:00 in UTC time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the Date object with a simple function. This is ideal if you are working with, for example, charting software and need to call the UTCfloor in several different places in order to properly align data; it helps to keep the calls simple and easy.

```js
Date.prototype.UTCfloor = function () {
    return new Date(Date.UTC(this.getUTCFullYear(), this.getUTCMonth(), this.getUTCDate()));
};

console.log(new Date().UTCfloor());
```

To note, this can also just be used as a regular function by passing in the Date.

```
function UTCfloor(date){
    return new Date(Date.UTC(date.getUTCFullYear(), date.getUTCMonth(), date.getUTCDate()));
}
```

Although, in my opinion it is easier to use the call shown above with the Date extension.

Comment: As a reminder,  don't mess with the prototype chain, avoid future SmooshGates.

Comment: As always, it depends. Is this a library with wide spread use? Then yeah, messing with this prototype chain should be avoided and the simple function is a better approach. Is this just being run inside of a script tag? Then it totally makes sense to design the page in an easy to develop manner, *especially* if you are sticking to vanilla and not using 3MB of external libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can construct it manually. Here's a solution in vanilla JS:

```js
function getUTCMidnight(dateObj) {
  let date = `${dateObj.getUTCDate()}`.padStart(2, "0");
  let month = `${dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1}`.padStart(2, "0");
  let year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
  return new Date(`${year}-${month}-${date}T00:00:00Z`);
}

function getCurrentUTCMidnight() {
  return getUTCMidnight(new Date());
}

console.log(getCurrentUTCMidnight());
console.log(getCurrentUTCMidnight().getTime());
console.log(getCurrentUTCMidnight() instanceof Date);
```